# why can't I get the value of the checkboxes in my datalist?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, datalist

I have a group of checkboxes in a datalist populated from a query. When checked, I want those values (strings) to be added to the string from another textbox. (Basically just notes, and the checkboxes make short work of typing oft-repeated comments.)

But for some reason, I can't get the checked boxes to get recognized in my codebehind. The checkboxes render in the form, and in fiddler, I can see that some checkboxes have an "on" value, but I can't get the values into the insert string.

Right now, I just have this wrapped in the click event of the button. Do I need to do a separate databinding on the datalist? If I need to do that, how do I get the rest of the values into the click event? I tried doing the databinding separately, and then calling the databind function from the click event, but the variables I created couldn't be found in the same context.

Here's the cs code:

```
 foreach (DataListItem item in StatusCheckboxDataList.Items)
            if (item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
            {
                {

                    CheckBox StatusProblemDescriptionCheckbox= (CheckBox)item.FindControl("StatusProblemDescriptionCheckbox");
                    HiddenField StatusProblemDescriptionHidden= (HiddenField)item.FindControl("StatusProblemDescriptionHidden");
                    if (StatusProblemDescriptionCheckbox != null)
                    {
                        if (StatusProblemDescriptionCheckbox.Checked == true)
                        {
                            string StatusProblemString = StatusProblemDescriptionHidden.Value;
                            StatusProblemString = "Errors Found: " + StatusProblemString + ", " + Status_notes.Text; //this is coming from the textbox... it's finding this just fine.
                            newstatusentry.s_notes = StatusProblemString;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            string StatusProblemString = Status_notes.Text;
                            newstatusentry.s_notes = StatusProblemString;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

It happens to be living inside an AjaxControlToolkit Accordion, but I removed the accordion, and still no go.

here's the aspx code

```
<asp:DataList ID="StatusCheckboxDataList" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="StatusProblemDescriptionCheckbox" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval ("statusprobDesc") %>' /><br />
     <asp:HiddenField ID="StatusProblemDescriptionHidden" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval ("statusprobDesc") %>' />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: Is Find Control Returning null, or are the StatusProblemDescriptionHidden.Text blank?

- In Page_load, Make sure you are are only performing databind when !IsPostBack
- Do your dev and testing without the ajax toolkit, then add it when it is working.

Comment: thanks. I think findcontrol is working, or I'd get an error on my if statment, right? So, if I do the databind, where does the click event get handled? In a separate void? (Tried this, but it wasn't seeing the "StatusProblemString" in my click event.) And yep on the ToolKit... I'll add later when the function is working!

Comment: did some more testing, created an ondatabinding event for the datalist... not sure if it made a difference, but I discovered this: It's only finding the LAST item in the collection. If I check the LAST checkbox in the DataList, it will recognize that selection, and add it to my string. But ONLY the last one. If I check the last one and any others, it still only recognizes the last checkbox. If I don't check the final box, no checkbox values make it into the string. Is that anything?

Comment: Anyone? I'm losing my mind on this! Tried separating it out as a databind, tried plugging the string into a hiddenfield on the aspx page, and nothing. ONLY THE LAST CHECKBOX IS EVER RECOGNIZED! This must mean something, right? I know the findcontrol is working because I changed the control name, and it found nothing. So at least I can tell it finds something. But why only the last checkbox? I suppose I could just make them all individual checkboxes on the aspx page, but that kind of defeats the purpose of the database, doesn't it?

Comment: I made them individual checkboxes, and then just added to the string as it checks each one. This is fine for now, as the values for these checkboxes are fairly permanent. But boy, I'd love to figure out how to read the values from a datalist and concatenate them into a string to use in a text field.

Comment: Be sure you are not ovewrirtting the test box values every time you loop through :
Use  newstatusentry.s_notes = newstatusentry.s_notes+ StatusProblemString;   

rather Than:
newstatusentry.s_notes = StatusProblemString;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure you are not ovewrirtting the test box values every time you loop through : Use

```
 newstatusentry.s_notes = newstatusentry.s_notes+ StatusProblemString;
```

rather Than:

```
 newstatusentry.s_notes = StatusProblemString
```